# My Galaxy Tab A SM-T510 won't unlock security screen with correct code or thru find my mobile unlock

Tags: samsung, lock-screens

My tablet won't unlock screen with correct code , clicks into wait try again in 29 seconds . Using the find my mobile site try to unlock screen that way , comes back with Something went wrong and does not unlock. Any other way to get into it without having to do a hard reset

Comment: unfortunately besides the official methods there is no other way. even bruteforce attack makes no sense because you already **know** code. i recommend to wait 72 hours and try again